# Use a wordwrap in a while loop

Tags: php, word-wrap

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo $row['title']
}
```

Hello, the code above outputs a title of a subject in a table. However, i want the title to break after a certain amount of characters and replace the last characters with three dots.

for example not

blalblablalbalbalblalbalblalba

but

blalblblalbalbla...

I think i have to do this with wordwrap like this...

```
$title= $row['title'];
$newtitle = wordwrap($title, xx, "...", true);
```

However, i have no clue how to put this in the while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you don't want wordwrap, but instead, you want sub string

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    //1) check if string lenth is too long (e.g. 10 characters)
    if(strlen($row['title'])>10){
        //2a) Truncate the string and append the ...
        echo substr($row['title'],0,10)." ...";
    }else echo the the string as it's not too long
    //2b)
    echo $row['title']
}
```

you might also need to modify this code to include characters that define your table...